# Is there no similar proof to change of variables for double integrals as there is for a single integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The single variable change of variable theorem states that, for any function $\varphi$ with integrable derivative, and a continuous function $f$:

$$\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)}f(x)dx=\int_a^bf(\varphi (x))\varphi '(x)dx$$

The proof is a really simple application of the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus. Is there no similar calculus proof, even if tedious (assuming similar restrictions), for the  double integral case:

$$\int \int_S f(x,y)dxdy =\int \int_R f(g(u,v),h(u,v)) |J|dudv$$

Considering also that a similar theorem to fundamental theorem of calculus exists for the double integrals. See for example: [Proof for the "Fundamental Calculus Theorem" for two variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161490/proof-for-the-fundamental-calculus-theorem-for-two-variables)

Comment: As I know there are no easy proofs for the multivariable case.

Comment: If you know about differential forms, you can write $dx = x_u du + x_v dv$, and similarly for $dy$, and then compute their wedge product. From the algebraic properties of wedge product, you will see that $dx \wedge dy = |J| du \wedge dv$.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you with this solution:

We first start to integrate with respect to *x*
$$\int \int f dxdy=\int dy\int f dx.$$

To evaluate it in the other coordinates, we have to express *dx* using *u,v* variables, and must be cautious about the meaning of "*dx*": $dx=(\delta x$ |$\delta y=0$). In terms of Jacobian matrix,
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \delta x \\
    \delta y  \\
    \end{pmatrix}=J \begin{pmatrix}
    \delta u \\
    \delta v  \\
    \end{pmatrix} ,\space  \space \space  J= \begin{pmatrix}
    h'_u & h'_v \\
    g'_u & g'_v \\
    \end{pmatrix},
$$
thus
$$
    \frac{1}{det(J)} \begin{pmatrix}
    g'_v & -h'_v \\
    -g'_u & h'_u \\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    \delta x \\
    \delta y(=0)  \\
    \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
    \delta u \\
    \delta v  \\
    \end{pmatrix},
$$
and
$$dx=\frac{det(J)}{g'_v}du.$$

We can naïvely replace this directly into the integral,

$$\int dy\int f dx= \int dy\int f \frac{det(J)}{g'_v}du \space  \space \space   (wrong),$$

however, this is wrong due to not respecting the *g(u,v)=y* condition (we are not actually on *y=const.* line by only sweeping *u* variable). We must instead force this condition using Dirac Delta function:

$$\int dy\int f dx= \int dy\int \int f \frac{det(J)}{g'_v}\biggl(\delta  (y-g)g'_vdv \biggr) du \space  \space \space   (correct).$$

Note that integration of the expression in the parenthesis amounts to one. One last step is to integrate *y* variable; finally

$$\int \int f dxdy=\int \int fdet(J) dudv.$$.