# Can we solve integral equations for a multivariable function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-equations

Integral equations are equations in which an unknown function appears under an integral sign. Can we solve integral equations when the function is multivariable and the integral is a multiple integral?

For example, I want to find a function $f(x,y)$ that is a solution of the following integral equation.

$$
\int_0^y\int_0^x f(x',y') dx'dy' =(x-y)^2
$$

How can we find the $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Try taking derivatives w.r.t. $y$ and $x$ on both sides.

Comment: And: To see if such a function can exist set $y$ to zero and $x$ to one.

Comment: >> Kurt G.
Yap, I have already done it. The left side is $f(x,y)$. I used the fundamental calculus theorem for two variables. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161490/proof-for-the-fundamental-calculus-theorem-for-two-variables)
The right side is $-2$. Then, $f(x,y)=-2$. Is that correct? I think I made some mistakes.

Comment: That was the mistake I first made :) . Can the integral of a negative function be positive ? Now consider my second comment .

Comment: >> Kurt G. No. It is impossible. This is why I posted this question. So, does it mean there is no solution to this integral equation?

Comment: That's what it means.

Comment: >> Kurt G. Thank you. I have posted my answer. Is that correct?

Comment: Take a peek at any book on potential theory for starters. After that Fredholm and Volterra integral equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve some kinds of integral equations for a multivariable function. But in the example,

$$
\int_0^y\int_0^x f(x',y') dx'dy' =(x-y)^2
$$

is unsolvable. When $x=0$ or $y=0$ on the left side, the right side has to be always $0$, however, the left side is not $0$ for $x=0$ or $y=0$.