# A scalar is equal to a vector? Leibniz rule of integration for multivariate Gaussian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, leibniz-integral-rule

The density of the multivariate Gaussian (=normal) distribution is given by
$$
f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}} \left|\Sigma\right|^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})}
$$

Suppose we integrate $f$ with respect to vector $\mathbf{x}$ over some subset $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, i.e., $v=\int_{\mathcal{S}} f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)d\mathbf{}$. Note that $\mathcal{S}$ is not a function of $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ or $\Sigma$ (or $\mathbf{x}$).  According to my knowledge, **the quantity $v$ should be a scalar**.

Further suppose we want to know how $v$ changes with respect to mean vector $\boldsymbol{\mu}.$ If we take the gradient
$$
w_1=\nabla v=\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{\mu}}v=\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{\mu}}\int_{\mathcal{S}} f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)d\mathbf{x}
$$
**we should get a vector** for $w_1$ because we are deriving a scalar by a vector.
The Leibniz rule of integration says that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{\mu}}\int_{\mathcal{S}} f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)d\mathbf{x} =\int_{\mathcal{S}}  \frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{\mu}}f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)d\mathbf{x}
$$

Now suppose $\mathcal{S}=\mathbb{R}^d$. Then, using simple calculus, we would get

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  \frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{\mu}}f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)d\mathbf{x} = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)d\mathbf{x} = w_2
$$
because $\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{\mu}}f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)d\mathbf{x} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)d\mathbf{x}$.
According to my understanding $w_2$ **should be a scalar**, because of the fundamental theorem of calculus. But this makes no sense because, as highlighted above, it would seem that $w_1=w_2$, i.e., **a vector is equal to a scalar?!** So I must have broken a rule somewhere, or misunderstood how the mentioned theorems worked. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: As I understand it, you are trying to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus in $\mathbb{R}$ to the gradient of a multivariable function defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But the analogous theorem for multivariable functions would be something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161490/proof-for-the-fundamental-calculus-theorem-for-two-variables).

Comment: @Suriya I don't understand which insights I should gain from the link you provided, because it is about taking second derivatives. The question only addresses first derivatives with respect to a vector. Can you please clarify?

Comment: When you take the gradient of a multivariate function you have a vector whose components are partial derivatives of the function. When you integrate each component you still get a vector. You cannot simply cancel the gradient with the integral.